# Is "length and length" any different than just "length" in Python?

Tags: python

I've found the following code snippet:

```
length = length and length or len(string)
```

To me it appears that this should be equivalent to:

```
length = length or len(string)
```

Can I collapse the expression `length and length` to just be `length` or will I get a different result in some cases?

Comment: `if length: length = length or len(string) else: length = False` would be equivalent to your `length = length and length or len(string)`. Also, `length or len(string)` can give the value of `len(string)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I was wrong! But it does seem that the statement will leave the value of `length` unchanged irrespective of the values of `length` or `string`. I wonder where William saw the code snippet...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Refreshed a little late... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line is nonsense. Let's take a look at the options we have:

- `length` is falsy (so `0`, an empty list, an empty string, etc.). Python will return the value of `length` because there is no point in looking at the rest of the expression as the `and` operator evaluates to `False` whatever the right-hand side evaluates to. It then tests `length or len(string)` and returns `len(string)`.
- `length` is not falsy. Python evaluates `length and length`, resolves that to the value of `length`, then tests `length or len(string)`, and because `length` is truthy, returns `length`. After all, `or` will now always resolve to `True` and there is no point in looking at `len(string)`.

This basically comes down to `length = length or len(string)`, the `length and length` is a no-op.

Comment: ... which is exactly what he was asking. I'm glad you corrected your answer, I was about to complain.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: `+++ out of caffeine error +++ redo from start +++`.

Comment: Sorry, Python doesn't natively support the "retry" construct in its exception mechanisms. Try a different language.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: The alternative response is `+++Divide By Cucumber Error. Please Reinstall Universe And Reboot +++` but caffeine is easier to come by.

Answer (score 2):

`length and length or len(string)` is exactly equivalent to `length or len(string)`.  I think that that whoever wrote this code expected it to avoid the `len(string)` call when `length` is falsy, but that is not the case.  For example:

```
>>> None and None or len('foo')
3
```

Since `and` had higher precedence than `or`, we can rewrite the expression as follows:

```
(length and length) or len('foo')
```

`length and length` will always evaluate to `length`, so the two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: *I* think what was being done is that the writer was familiar with the "x and y or z" almost-ternary-expression idiom and just applied it without thinking.